# subclipse: same userID, different machines

Tags: android, svn, subclipse

I have a very basic question about SVN. I know SVN has pretty strict rules about things & was wonedring if I would mess up my project if I tried this.

I use two computers regularly - onsite & from home. I have Eclipse(Galelio) + subclipse(1.6.x) installed on both. If I were to checkout the same project from SVN repository on different machines using the SAME user ID, would there be any sort of problems during commits or updates?

I will be committing from different machines regularly, but of course it will be the same user ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SVN, each commit is identified, no matter of the user that made the commit.

User that made the commit is only an information like the commit message, nothing more.

So, you will be able to commit on your 2 working repositories without less or more conflicts than if the commits were done by different users ;)

Answer (score 1):

SVN does not track checkouts, it does not matter what username you use.  You could even zip up a checkout on one machine move it to another and unzip it.

At commit time, the username you provide will determine the author for the commit.  On your other machine, which does not have this commit, an svn up will bring in this new commit fine.

In short, the author name is just a piece of information for history log.  It is not going to cause any problems to use the same repos from different machines.